# Perl command for same behaviour as readlink?

Tags: perl, gnu-coreutils

What is the equivalent Perl command to the GNU coreutils command [`readlink -f`](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/readlink-invocation.html)?

> If any component of the file name except the last one is missing or unavailable, readlink produces no
>   output and exits with a nonzero exit code. A trailing slash is
>   ignored.

Comment: note: readlink is not a part of bash.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [Cwd](http://perldoc.perl.org/Cwd.html#abs_path-and-friends):

```
use Cwd 'abs_path';
my $path = "/some/arbitrary/path";
print abs_path($path);
```

Test:

```
for q in exists imaginary imarginary/imaginary ; do
   echo "$q"
   echo -n "readlink -f: " ; readlink -f "$q"
   echo -n "abs_path:    " ; perl -MCwd=abs_path -E'say abs_path $ARGV[0]' "$q"
   echo
done
```

Output:

```
exists
readlink -f: /home/eric/exists
abs_path:    /home/eric/exists

imaginary
readlink -f: /home/eric/imaginary
abs_path:    /home/eric/imaginary

imaginary/imaginary
readlink -f: abs_path:
```

Comment: Thanks, I wanted to make sure `Cwd abs_path` in Perl and GNU coreutils `readlink -f` have the same behaviour.

Comment: @200508519211022689616937 Yes.

Comment: There was a bug. I fixed it and added a test. Note that `abs_path`'s behaviour can vary by system type. (You should get the same behaviour on all unixy systems.)

Answer (score 0):

As a total Perl rookie, I'm happy to say I have figured out this STDIN solution all by myself (after several tries, remember that Perl's learning curve IS known to be steep).
devnull's solution was great with no doubt, but it was a little too "scriptish" for my taste - whereas I'd sometimes just want to **pipe** a perl one-liner to an `echo`'ed string, like this:

```
echo "/home/user/somesymlinkedpath" | perl -MCwd=abs_path -nle 'print abs_path $_'
```

So as there might be more people around who want to know about how to code this kind of piped form (making `perl` read the argument from STDIN), I've decided to post it here too.